# Search hash values for substring and return key in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have an array:

`array = ["One is enough", "Two is a couple", "Where's the beef?", "One"]`

I then have a hash:

```
hash = {"one" => "Defined",
        "two" => "Test"
       }
```

I need to loop over each object in `array` and see if that object contains a substring that is found in the `hash` keys. If it is found, it should return the `hash` value. Otherwise, it should return `undefined`. The end goal is to create an array that looks like this:

`final_array = ["Defined,"Test","Undefined","Defined"]`

How can I write that loop effectively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an approach :

```
array = ["One is enough", "Two is a couple", "Where's the beef?", "One"]
hash = {"one" => "Defined","two" => "Test"}

array.map{|e| hash.find(proc{["undefined"]}){|k,v| e.downcase.include? k}.last}
# => ["Defined", "Test", "undefined", "Defined"]
```

Explanation:

***[Enumerable#find](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-find)*** will be good idea. As doc is saying - **Passes each entry in enum to block. Returns the first for which block is not false. *If no object matches, calls ifnone and returns its result* when it is specified, or returns nil otherwise.**

I used `Array#map`,and passing each element string,to the block. Now inside the block I called `#find` on `hash`. Now `hash.find` passing each `key/value` pair to the `hash.find` method block. Inside that block I am calling `String#include?` method on `e`,passing *key* as argument to the `#include?` method. If `#include?` test results `true`,then `key/value` of that iteration is returned,otherwise default argument `proc{["undefined"]}.call` is being performed.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Works perfectly - Any chance you can explain what's going on in that method? I've got to get better at using and understanding these one liners.

Answer (score 0):

```
hash = {"one" => "Defined", "two" => "Test"}
array = ["One is enough", "Two is a couple", "Where's the beef?", "One"]

hash.default = "Undefined"
keys = hash.keys
array.map {|a| hash[(a.split.map(&:downcase) & keys).first]}
```

- if hash does not contain a key 'k', hash[k] => "Undefined"
- a.split.map(&:downcase) changes, for example, a = "One is Enough" to "one is enough"
- the intersection with keys equals ["one"], ["two"], [nil], ["one"], respectively
- .first is to extract the hash key from the 1-element arrays
- the hash is evaluated at the computed hash key, with hash[nil] => "Undefined" (default)